# Medical robots models

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a lecturer in a university that just created a degree in "medical IT engineer".

The students have basic robotics courses, such as geometrical modeling and sensor-based control. I'd love to teach this topic using a medical robot simulator in Rviz, but the nearest I found is Care-O-Bot, which is not really a medical robot.

I already made the teaching code to play with any URDF, so I just need a medical related model.

Have you by chance heard of any existing ressources for this topic ?

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48975/medical-robots-models/) by [Olivier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3659/olivier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in [this link](http://www.ros.org/news/2012/03/surgical-robot-system-from-university-of-bern.html).

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0